# How do i get a data entry from a directory full of xml files and put them into an array in powershell?

Tags: powershell

I currently have  script that will crawl a directory and pull the first 4 characters of the xml file name, place them in an array, then create a new folder for each unique array entry. I would like to make a similar script that reads the contents of the xml files in the directory, gets a value from the file, populates the array with that value, and then create a list of directories with the unique values from the array.

I am very new to powershell and have not had any luck with parsing XML files. Here is my current code:

```
### Global Variables

$Global:server = "SERVER"
$Global:archive = "\\$server\PCMS\Archive"
$Global:xmlDir = "\\$server\PCMS\Archive\xml"
$Global:date = Get-Date -Format yyyyMMdd
$Global:dateFolder = "$archive\$date"
$Global:manifest = "\\$server\PCMS\Temp"


### Functions


# Create a folder with today's date
function new-folder
{
    New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path $Global:archive -Name $Global:date
}

# Analyze files and get store number
function files2dir 
{
    $Global:array = @((Get-ChildItem -Path $xmlDir -Recurse -Include 0*.xml -Name -ErrorAction Stop))
    $Global:array = $array.SubString(0,4) | Get-Unique #gets first 4 characters of a file and only keeps unique items
}


If (Test-Path -Path $dateFolder) {
    Main
}
else {
    new-folder
}

## Main script
function Main {

files2dir
$integer = 0

foreach($file in $array){
    New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path $dateFolder -Name $array[$integer] -erroraction 'silentlycontinue'
    $integer = $integer + 1
}

}
```

And here is an example of the xml files in the directory. I am trying to get the storeCode value

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beanstoreTransaction>
<transactionSession>
<Session class="redacted" action="0">
<version>
  <database>Redacted</database>
  <build>Redacted</build>
</version>
  <companyCode>XXXX</companyCode>
  <frequency>YYYYY</frequency>
  <openMethod>2</openMethod>
  <sessionID>ZZZ</sessionID>
  <startDateTime>2020-02-24 05:12:47.00</startDateTime>
  <statusStatusCode>Q</statusStatusCode>
  <storeCode>1111</storeCode>
  <tillTillNumber>9</tillTillNumber>
  <tradingDate>2020-02-24</tradingDate>
  <transactionNumber>RRRR</transactionNumber>
</Session>
</beanstoreTransaction>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PowerShell is heavily XML based and has built-in cmdlets to deal with properly formatted XML files...

```
Get-Command -Name '*xml*'
<#
# Results

CommandType     Name                Version    Source  
-----------     ----                -------    ------  
...                      
Cmdlet          ConvertTo-Xml       3.1.0.0    Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility           
...                     
Cmdlet          Export-Clixml       3.1.0.0    Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility           
Cmdlet          Import-Clixml       3.1.0.0    Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility           
Cmdlet          Merge-XMLFile       5.0.0.1    Sorlov.PowerShell                      
...                     
Cmdlet          Select-Xml          3.1.0.0    Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility
#>
```

... thus, use the examples from those cmdlets. Yet, even it did not, it can use the .Net namespace to do so.

```
[System.Xml]$XmlDocument = Get-Content -Path 'D:\temp\XmlData.xml'
$XmlDocument.
```

Just search for ['PowerShell parsing XML'](https://www.bing.com/search?q=%27powershell%20parsing%20xml%27&qs=n&form=QBRE&sp=-1&pq=%27powershell%20parsing%20xml%27&sc=3-24&sk=&cvid=51C7772E5F68475F9640D80A38153D9F)

> [PowerShell Data Basics: XML](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sysadmin/powershell/powershell-data-basics-xml)
>
> Accessing XML with XPath With the file loaded into an XmlDocument
>   object, you can then  navigate the XML tree with XPath. To select a
>   set of nodes use the SelectNodes method:

```
$xdoc = New-Object System.Xml.XmlDocument
$file = resolve-path('.\sample.xml')
$xdoc.load($file)

[xml] $xdoc = Get-Content '.\sample.xml'
$xdoc = [xml] (Get-Content '.\sample.xml')
$xdoc.SelectNodes('//author')
```

> [Powershell: Parsing XML Part 1](https://www.thomasmaurer.ch/2010/06/powershell-parsing-xml-part-1)
>
> [Use PowerShell to Parse an XML File and Sort the Data](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/use-powershell-to-parse-an-xml-file-and-sort-the-data)
>
> [Parsing XML Files with PowerShell](https://jamesmccaffrey.wordpress.com/2007/12/02/parsing-xml-files-with-powershell)
>
> [PowerShell offers several ways to read XML documents, without writing
>   a lot of code](https://www.business.com/articles/powershell-read-xml-files)

Since XML is just text, you can also just use the Get-Content cmdlet with Select-String cmdlet or RegEx to extract text from any text-based file.